# Can you learn functional programming in C?

Tags: c, paradigms

As a result of the [comment discussion here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/116643/why-has-the-rate-of-programming-language-popularization-slowed-down-in-recent-de#comment-213333), I wonder whether you can learn Functional Programming in C?

Comment: Regardles of whether you can or cannot, you **shouldn't**.

Comment: Absolutely! The first step is to write a Lisp interpreter ;-)

Comment: If I got it right, the question should have been about learning various concepts with pseudocode, without *any*  real language at all.

Comment: @SK-logic: To put it mildly, very few programmers have learned programming purely with pseudocode, most had to get their hands dirty and their faces smacked with error messages from the compiler/interpreter.

Comment: @sbi, some of the best programmers have learned programming when compilers had no error messages at all. Coding on punch cards requires a bit of understanding of what you're doing long before you'll have a chance to run the code. And needless to mention that the basis for the functional programming had been established long before a first computer was built.

Comment: Can you learn driving using a Ford Model T? Absolutely.

Comment: @SK-logic: Yes, some of the best did. But looking at the demand now, those _were_, as I said, _very few_ programmers. So I see my argument still standing.

Comment: @sbi, your original question is about whether one *can*  learn, not on statistics of how many people actually do learn. And historical evidence shows that learning without any real language is not only possible but gives the best result.

Comment: @SK-logic: My original question (stemming from the comment discussion I linked to) was whether it makes sense to learn FP using C. However, I feared a "does it make sense to..." would be closed within minutes, so I rephrased it. But even if taken literally, I think it's clear that a "can you..." question refers to _plural_ "you", and about that only statistical statements can be made. (Of course, you are free to keep twisting my words in my mouth, but I still think I know what I am after and I also believe it shows in my question, if readers only apply some common sense.)

Comment: @sbi: Many many programmers have learned to program using only psudo-code. Compiled and interpreted programming languages are not as old as programmable computing machines, and algorithms would be expressed in psudo-code, often by someone who never directly programmed a computer. Someone else might come along later and implement the algorithm in some assembly or machine language (flipping lots of switches or making cable connections).

Comment: @nategoose:  My original question (stemming from the comment discussion I linked to) was whether it makes sense to learn FP using C. However, I feared a "does it make sense to..." would be closed within minutes, so I rephrased it. But even if taken literally, I think it's clear that a "can you..." asks whether the language is a good enough fit to make it easy. As for pseudo-code: Would you pick an imperative or a functional type of pseudo code? (FWIW, having grown up on the wrong side of the Iron Curtain, pen and paper is how I "programmed" in the beginning. It's not very effective, though.)

Comment: @sbi: You should look into Static Single Assignment (SSA) which is a common way that compilers "think" about programs internally for some of their optimizations and warning/error analysis.  SSA is a functional representation, and being familiar with functional programming can help you to write more reliable and more efficient programs as long as you know what aspects of functional style a compiler can take advantage of.

Comment: @nategoose: So you're telling me knowing about FP is good even if you do not write FP. I am not sure what to make of this, as this question wasn't even discussed here.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Obviously you can **do** functional programming in C. In theory, you can also **learn** functional programming principles in C, but the language doesn't make it easy.

I assume you have at least a bit of a background in OOP; if you do, you should be aware that OOP can be done in C, including polymorphism, getters/setters, visibility rules, etc. etc., but it's fairly painful to do so, and you need to know both OOP and C inside-out to pull it off. It's much the same with FP.

What you **should** be doing is first learn a functional programming language (most of them have surprisingly simple syntax rules; it's not the syntax that makes them hard to learn), and *then* let your newly-acquired wisdom influence the way you write C.

---

As per request, a few things you can learn from FP and then apply in, say, C, C++ or Java:

- Avoid state, especially shared mutable state
- Appreciate pure functions
- Appreciate lazy evaluation
- Being able to model in terms of verbs rather than nouns
- Being able to approach problems recursively as well as iteratively
- Using higher-order functions
- Thinking of functions as just another kind of value, that you can pass around and combine with other values
- Using first-class functions as an alternative for object-based polymorphism

Comment: Can you provide specific examples of how C / C++ / Java programmers do can benefit from LISP wisdom. It makes sense in theory, but I am looking for something concrete.

Comment: @Job, What concrete benefit can there be? It expands their minds and maybe makes them think of excessive mutable state as a bad thing, what more could you ask for?

Comment: So can I conclude from this that, while it is possible to learn (some) FP in C, it makes no sense to do that?

Comment: @Job: I have learned FP when I learned LISP as a student many years ago. About a decade later I applied FP in template meta-programming.

Comment: @Job: I can think of quite a few examples, yes. I'll update my answer in a second.

Comment: @sbi, my favourite way of learning new languages and concepts is via implementing them. And C is quite a decent language for implementing a compiler. So, yes, you can learn FP with C.

Comment: @SK-logic: There's no need to shadow the discussion we have under the question. What I've replied there applies to this statement as well.

Answer (score 11):

C can be hacked to offer some functional concepts:

- Closures via [FFCALL](http://www.haible.de/bruno/packages-ffcall.html),
- Nested functions via a [GCC extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html)

This [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216037/what-tools-are-there-for-functional-programming-in-c) will tell you more. But although it seems possible to do functional programming (or a large subset of) in C, hacks and compiler extensions and whatever are not the best way to learn of a concept.

To actually *learn* functional programming your best bet is one of the prominent functional programming languages like [Lisp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_%28programming_language%29) and its dialects ([Clojure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clojure), [Scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheme_%28programming_language%29)), [Erlang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_%28programming_language%29), and [Haskell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell_%28programming_language%29). Any one of those are perfect tools that work within the functional programming mindset.  [F#](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F_Sharp_%28programming_language%29) is also a good candidate if you have a .Net background, but it's a multi paradigm language, not strictly a functional programming language.

---

As [tdammers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/18930/tdammers) notes in the comments:

> Actually, LISP, clojure and scheme are also multi-paradigm; Haskell,
>   while being pure and default-lazy, also allows for imperative
>   programming while in a monadic context, and it has extensive support
>   for concurrent processing. All of these have mechanisms that implement
>   large parts of the wisdom gathered in the OOP world - encapsulation,
>   inheritance, single-responsibility, composition, etc. It's not so much
>   about whether a language ALLOWS other paradigms; it's about which
>   paradigm forms a language's starting point.

To the best of my knowledge Lisp and its dialects and Erlang are better candidates than F# because they encourage functional programming over other paradigms, what [tdammers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/18930/tdammers) beautifully states as *a language's starting point*. F# does encompass functional programming but does not encourage it over its other supported paradigms, imperative and oo programming.

Comment: Regarding your last sentence: In that case I'd argue that F# is a better candidate because it won't trap you in a functional mindset. In a multi-paradigm language, when you start hammering screws, you can just switch to a screwdriver. When trapped in a single paradigm you may miss the difference between the screw and the nail.

Comment: Well the question is on how to learn functional programming, not programming. I'm assuming that the op has some experience in a multi paradigm language and wants the most efficient way to learn functional programming, in which case F# is a good candidate but not a perfect one. *Trapped* in a single paradigm is obviously the best way when you are looking to learn of that single paradigm as you don't have to deal with everything that's not it.

Comment: I believe that learning when the paradigm is well-suited and when it is ill-suited for a certain task is a part of learning it, perhaps the most important.

Comment: Actually, LISP, clojure and scheme are also multi-paradigm; Haskell, while being pure and default-lazy, also allows for imperative programming while in a monadic context, and it has extensive support for concurrent processing. All of these have mechanisms that implement large parts of the wisdom gathered in the OOP world - encapsulation, inheritance, single-responsibility, composition, etc. It's not so much about whether a language ALLOWS other paradigms; it's about which paradigm forms a language's starting point.

Comment: @tdammers I've added your comment in the answer, hope that's ok.

Comment: @MartinhoFernandes: One could argue that being trapped in a single paradigm is *the perfect* way to learn when it is really a pain in the ass :-)

Comment: @YannisRizos: Sure, no problem.

Comment: You wrote that F# is multi-paradigm. Do you know how ML and Ocaml are classified? Are they both multi-paradigm? I once read that SML is multi-paradigm (imperative / functional) and Ocaml multi-paradigm (object-oriented / functional). Is this correct?

Comment: I do not see how Lisp encourages functional programming more than F#/OCaml do. Learning Lisp after I learnt Scheme and OCaml, I was actually really surprised how much Lisp *actually* encourages imperative programming – more than Scheme does.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot learn all aspects of functional programming in C. But surely you can start functional style programming with any imperative language. These starting bits are- "How to keep things pure while programming." And it can be done C also. Check this blog post for details-

http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2011/07/24/get-started-functional-programming/

Answer (score 2):

## TL;DR

Functional programming is about closures and their applications. Unless someone is able to show you a descent closure library for C, forget about using C to learn functional programming.

## What is functional programming?

The cardinal concept of functional programming is the notion of [closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)) which roughly speaking, captures a function together with variables bindings.  Besides
the pervasive use of closures, there a few other distinctive traits in functional programming, like the use of recursive functions and immutable values (both play well together).  These traits are more a cultural issue than anything else, and there is no technical obstruction to use them in virtually any language, this is why I focus on closures in my answer: not every language allow to easily create closures.

## Three illustrations of closures usefulness

A typical use of closures is the implementation of privacy mechanisms. For instance the Javascript code – in the examples I picked Javascript because it is a functional language with a so-called “C-like syntax” and your question suggests that you are familiar with C:

```
create_counter = function()
{
  var x = 0;
  var counter = function()
  {
    ++x;
    return x;
  };
  return counter;
}
```

Then with

```
a = create_counter();
b = create_counter();
```

we have two functions `a` and `b` counting disjoint collections.  The point of the example is that the variables `x` is captured by the closure defining the `counter` closure and each time a new `counter` closure`is instantiated by the function, it gets its fresh own idea of what`x` is.

Another typical use of closures is the definition of partial applications of functions.  Assume that that we have a reporting facility similar to `syslog` implementing a function

```
var log = function(priority, message) {
…
};
```

where the arguments `priority` and `message` are expected to be strings, the first one being one of `"debug"`, `"info"`, and so on.  We can define a log factory like this:

```
var logWithPriority = function(priority) {
  return function(message) {
    log(priority, message);
  };
};
```

and use it to define specialised versions of our log facility:

```
var debug = logWithPriority("debug");
var info = logWithPriority("info");
…
```

This is very useful, because instead of writing error-prone `for`-loops like this

```
for(i = 0; i < journal.length; ++i) {
   log("info", journal[i]);
}
```

we can write the cleaner, shorter and much simpler (there is no `i`, that's *much* better):

```
journal.forEach(logWithPriority("info"));
```

A third important application field of closures is the implementation of lazy evaluation – note that special language support can provide for a better implementation.

A lazy function, instead of performing a straight computation, returns a closure which can be called (or “forced” in the jargon of laziness) to perform the question. The motivation for doing this is that it separates preparing a computation and performing a computation.  A practical example of this is regular expression compilation: if a program compiles a lot of regular expressions at startup-time, it will need a lot of time to start. If instead we lazily compile the regular expressions and force them as we need them, then our program can quickly start.  Of course, regular-expressions can be substituted here with any structure requiring considerable initialisation time.

Here is how to implement lazy evaluation with closures.  Consider the classical implementation of the *arrayMax* function returning the *max* in an array:

```
function arrayMax(array) {
  return array.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return Math.min(a, b);
  };
}
```

The lazy variant would be:

```
function arrayMax(array) {
  var memo = null;
  function actuallyCompute() {
    if(memo === null) {
      memo = array.reduce(function(a, b) {
        return Math.min(a, b);
      });
    }
    return memo;
  }
  return actuallyCompute;
}
```

The returned value is a closure which can be used to compute the value or retrieve it another time if it has been already computed.

With these three examples, we should be confident that **closures and their applications are the core of functional programming.**

## Conclusion

Learning functional programming means learning how to program with closures. As a consequence, languages allowing the easy manipulation of closures, and especially the partial application of functions, should be regarded when looking for a language to study functional programming.  Conversely, languages where closures cannot be easily manipulated would be poor choices.

Comment: Thanks for this nice sample. BTW, as you define var info, wouldn't it be journal.forEach(info)  ?

Comment: Yes, it would be an appropriate variant! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think that the tools you use influence your learning a lot. It's almost impossible to learn programming concepts for which the programming language you use does not provide the means to make use of. Sure, you can always learn a few things, but you cannot learn it properly.

But that is academic anyway, because, as [Martinho says in his comment](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/116863/can-you-learn-functional-programming-in-c#comment-213752), even if you *could* learn functional programming, you *should* not try to do that, because there are languages where this is *much* easier.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't learn functional programming in C, but in a strict functional language (Haskell, Caml, Erlang, etc . . .).

If you are new to functional, you will never really get it with a non functional language. More likely, you will train yourself to do what you think is functional programming and learn things the wrong way. And it is always harder to « relearn » things the right way than learnt them the right way at first.

Anyway, I think doing functional in C is a good exercise for someone who already knows functional. Because that person will learn what's going on behind the hood - what the computer is really doing.